# How to compute this characteristic polynomial when composing two number fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

In Cohen's *Advanced Topics in Computational Number Theory*, Algorithm 2.1.9, page 60:
In the first step, we need to find an integer $k$ such that the characteristic polynomial of $\theta_2(\theta_1+k)$ is squarefree. But the aim of the algorithm is to compute a compositum of two number fields $K$ and $L$; $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are generators of $K$ and $L$, so they are in different number fields.

For computing the characteristic polynomial of an element of a number field, we can use method described in *A course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory*, H.Cohen, Proposition 4.3.4, p164, which make uses of resultants.

How can I compute the characteristic polynomial of $\theta_2(\theta_1+k)$ without knowing the compositum of $K$ and $L$?

Comment: Those two fields should already be in a common field: the notion of composite field, in general, is not well-defined for abstract fields.  For example, if $K$ and $L$ are *abstractly* isomorphic to $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$, the degree $[KL:\mathbf Q]$ is ambiguous.  If $K = L$ then $[KL:\mathbf Q] = [K:\mathbf Q] = 3$.  If $K$ and $L$ are *distinct* fields inside an algebraic closure of $\mathbf Q$ (there are three such fields in $\overline{\mathbf Q}$), then $[KL:\mathbf Q] = 6$.  In short, you have to put $K$ and $L$ into a common field before $KL$ even makes any sense (in general).

Comment: For some pairs of number fields $K$ and $L$, all possible meanings of the composite field $KL$ are isomorphic to each other, e.g., if $K$ and $L$ are Galois over $\mathbf Q$.  You might want to look up ambiguity about the possible meaning of "linear disjointness" of abstract fields (as opposed to subfields of a common field). See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8324/what-does-linearly-disjoint-mean-for-abstract-field-extensions.

Comment: @KCd However, in this book the common field is $\bar{\textbf{Q}}$. Even simple arithmetic in this field is difficult to practice, not ever characteristic polynomial for such a general element. I'm finding a practical algorithm.

Comment: If $K = \mathbf Q(\theta_1)$ and $L = \mathbf Q(\theta_2)$ inside a common field (such as the composite of their Galois closures, which is well-defined up to isomorphism), their composite field $KL$ by definition is $\mathbf Q(\theta_1, \theta_2)$. By the proof of the primitive element theorem, $\mathbf Q(\theta_1, \theta_2) = \mathbf Q(\theta_1 + c\theta_2)$ for some rational number $c$, where $c$ can be all but at most finitely many choices (the proof of the primitive element theorem indicates which $c$ to avoid). In practice $c = 1$ often works; not always of course, but often.

Comment: @KCd It's indeed a method, as described in *Advanced Topics in Computational Number Theory*, Algorithm 2.1.8. But Algorithm 2.1.9 is just for ``another" method of composing two number fields, which usually gives simpler result, so it wouldn't use the previous.